# What is the best way to add a JavaScript lib to next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm new to next.js and am trying to migrate a project. I'm having trouble knowing how to include Bootstrap.js file in a page or in the entire site. I see how to include the CSS but not the JavaScript. Do I just add a cdn path to the public index.html file?

It's hard to know if it's getting included, because I don't see it pulling in in the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be creating a `_app.js` file. This file lives in the root of your pages directory. This will allow you to control all of the aspects of what's loaded app wide.

```
import 'bootstrap';
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

If however you load from the CDN then you would need to update your layout to load the script directly.

```
export function Layout(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <script src="...acdnpath"/>
            </Head>
            {props.children}
        </>
    );
}
```

I would recommend the former rather than the latter approach. This will allow next to start smartly detecting whats being loaded and when to help improve performance.

Comment: That helped move me along. Now that I've got import 'bootstrap' I'm getting Error: Cannot find module 'popper.js'. 
I tried installing popper and importing it, but I'm not losing the error.

Comment: how is popper installed? Whats the package name?

Comment: Bootstrap 5 is doing away with jquery, but popper.js is apparently still a dependency. I’ve given up. I dropped back to bootstrap 4 and using react-bootstrap which implements the modules for me.